# Increase primary-key column size having numerous dependencies

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

**Scenario:** I have a table (Customer). It has composite key out of which one is "Relationship_num" which has a size varchar(30).There is ample data in it. And 21 dependent tables.

**Problem:** Inserting a record which has relationship_num greater than the size of the column. So now i want to increase its size.

**Unsuccessful Work around:** When I made an attempt to alter the size, it displays error:        The object 'PK_CUSTOMER' is dependent on column 'RELATIONSHIP_NUM'.And 21 other errors of those tables which has the dependency on Customer table.

Then I tried to drop 'PK_CUSTOMER':

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER] DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_CUSTOMER]
```

which resulted in following error:

The constraint 'PK_CUSTOMER' is being referenced by table 'some-table', foreign key constraint 'RefCUSTOMER447'.Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Now making scripts(create and drop) of all these constraints could me cumbersome.

Plz help me out with this!

Comment: Have you tried increasing the size of the columns in the child tables before increasing the parent one ?

Comment: There are around 21 child tables... Therefore, i was trying for some smart technique

Comment: Right, this should not be done by hand. You should be able to adapt this example to modify the size of the child columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441251/how-to-get-list-of-child-tables-for-a-database-table

Comment: It worked! But there were 27 tables which it displayed. when i tried to change size of the column in one of those listed tables. That table was having other dependencies due to which it didn't change the column size of that table. Its getting cumbersome!!! What should i do with this gut

Comment: What additional dependencies ? Like a reference to a composite key including the abovementioned column ? In this case you can add recursion to the suggested query. Or simply apply it to the blocking table and hope it doesn't recurse too much for a manual input :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating scripts you can do it manually.Shortly it will take 1 minute.

```
1.Go to design view of your table colums.
2.Right click on the primary key.
3.Choose Relationships.
4.Remove all references from there.
5.Alter your table.
6.Re add your References.
```